# scons adding --prefix option

Tags: scons

What is the typical use-case for adding `--prefix` support to a scons build?

Currently I use Variables to persist user options from the command-line, but that requires I use the name `PREFIX` to be recognized as a variable. The docs show a way to specify the preifx using `AddOption` but then this option must be specified everytime scons is run: it isn't persisted like the variables.

What is the typical way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Add/GetOption to create an option the user can provide on the command line.

After, yous users will need to set the environment variable **SCONSFLAGS** with options they want to provide to SCons everytime. SCons will read this variable everytime.
http://www.scons.org/doc/2.0.1/HTML/scons-user/c2076.html

It's not a good idea to have many environment variable on the user machine because you lost the documentation and which variable you really need to compile.